# How to create Pragmatically Shared Mail Box on Office 365

Tags: .net-core, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am working on .NET CORE application and have requirement to create shared mailBox from .net application automatically, meaning admin user will enter email address and .net application go and create Shared mailbox with given email address automatically. later on I need to create events which will fire when email receive or error occur in getting mail.

Our mail exchange is on Office-365

I am aware of Microsoft Graph which can access mailboxes and do all sort of 'Get' related activities but not sure if I can perform admin work i.e. create shared mailbox? if yes! how can I do that???

if not, then how can achieve this task??/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [New-Mailbox PowerShell commandlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-mailbox?view=exchange-ps) spawned from your .net application.